# Why text in hidden fields while I scrolling is clearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I use UITableView.
If I change text in text field and then scroll down this text field is clearing.
Why text in hidden fields while I scrolling UITableView is clearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the table cells will get reused by cellAtRowInIndexPath as soon as it the user scrolls the cell off the screen. To preserve the content of the table cell you need to have the content stored into an NSArray in the table controller as soon as the user finishes editing text. If the user scroll back to your original row, read the text from the NSArray and set it back into the textField.

Comment: In what moment i should store content of table cell?

Comment: when the textfield finishes editing, for instance. You can listen to textField delegate events to catch when the user finishes editing the text field.

Comment: If i edit text field and then simple scroll down (without begin editing other field), event "text field finish editing" not raised.

Comment: I resolved the problem, i compare reference of text field for detecting what text field is current editing- it is mistake.